# An $L^1$ function whose Fourier series converges but not to itself

Tags: fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Do we have an $L^1$ function whose Fourier series converges almost everywhere but not to itself?

Comment: Please make that an answer so this is no longer unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Answered by [alpha](https://mathoverflow.net/users/45681/alpha) on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/156672):

> If the partial sums of the Fourier series converge to a function $g$ a.e., then so do the Cesaro means.  But these converge in the $L^1$-sense to the original function.  So the answer to your question is no.